# How do I link against Intel TBB on Mac OS X with GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, intel, tbb

I can't for the life of me figure out how to compile and link against the Intel TBB library on my Mac. I've run the commercial installer and the tbbvars.sh script but I can't figure this out. I have a feeling it is something really obvious and it's just been a bit too long since I've done this kind of thing.

tbb_test.cpp

```
#include <tbb/concurrent_queue.h>

int main() {
    tbb::concurrent_queue<int> q;
}
```

`g++ tbb_test.cpp -I /Library/Frameworks/TBB.framework/Headers -ltbb`

...can't find the symbols.

Cheers!

UPDATE:

`g++ tbb_test.cpp -I /Library/Frameworks/TBB.framework/Headers -L /Library/Frameworks/TBB.framework/Libraries/libtbb.dylib`

works!

Comment: @SilverSun, you should still probably use the "-framework" option... since it is equivalent, and it will also search in all framework paths (i.e. it will also work if the framework is in ~/Library/Frameworks or /System/Library/Frameworks). Also, when you have "umbrella frameworks", the "-framework" option will get everything, while you would need more options than what you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a framework instead of a traditional library, you need to use `-framework`, like:

```
g++ tbb_test.cpp -o tbb_test -framework TBB
```

Instead of:

```
g++ tbb_test.cpp -o tbb_test -I /Library/Frameworks/TBB.framework/Headers -ltbb
```

Comment: `-framework` isn't documented much in the manpage, but I think it indicates you want to *build* a framework. My best theory about his problem is that `tbb` needs capitalization.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, "-framework" is in the documentation on Mac OS X (it's an Apple extension to GCC). It means you want to link against the framework, not that you want to build one. For example, to link against the Foundation framework, you use "-framework Foundation".

Comment: This was asked/answered in 2010, so it would not surprise me if the information is now obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

According to the TBB [Getting Started Guide](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/uploads/81/91/Latest%20Open%20Source%20Documentation/Getting_Started.pdf) (page 3 of the current version), there are some scripts in the $INSTALL/bin directory that will set the right environment variables if you run `source` on them (e.g. `source bin/tbbvars.sh`). Once you do that, you no longer need to specify `-I` and `-L` in your `g++` command line, which is tedious, error prone, and most of all ugly. But you still have to use `-ltbb` :'(. This advice also applies to those using other Unix-like OSs, such as Linux.